# How to make chrome run with GPU on ec2 instance

Tags: google-chrome, gpu, xvfb

I'm running an ec2 instance with GPU ( g4dn.xlarge ) with image "Deep Learning Base AMI (Amazon Linux 2) Version 43.0" installed.

I tried to run chrome with webgl support but no luck. I start a Xvfb window and run chrome inside it with `--enable-webgl` and `--use-gl=desktop`

The `nvidia-smi` still show `No running processes found`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.142.00   Driver Version: 450.142.00   CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   28C    P8    10W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?